# Suppose $v_1,...,v_m$ is linearly independent in $V$ and $w \in V$. Prove that $\dim(\operatorname{span}(v_1+w,...,v_m+w))\geq m−1$.

Tags: linear-algebra

This is a follow up to [If $v_1,...,v_m$ are linearly independent, then the span $v_1+w,...,v_m+w$ has dimension $\ge m-1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1269123/if-v-1-v-m-are-linearly-independent-then-the-span-v-1w-v-mw-has-d)

I want to prove it using $\dim(U_1 + U_2) = \dim(U_1) + \dim(U_2) - \dim(U_1 \cap U_2); \dim(U_1 \cap U_2) = 0$.
But can't seem to find $\dim(U_1 \cap U_2)$ so that we obtain $\geq m-1$.

Comment: span of $(v_i+w)$'s is not the sum of span of $v_i$'s and span of $w$.

Comment: Oh?  I thought $c_1v_1=...+c_mv_m + (c_1+...+c_m)w$ reduces to $v+w$ for $v \in V$ and $w \in W$ which means its the same as the sum?  Where I go wrong?

Comment: But span of $v_i$'s plus span of $w$ contains all vectors of the form $\sum c_iv_i+cw$. Here $c$ need not be equal to $\sum c_i$.